# what do next when equal variances of a one-way ANOVA are not assumed?

Tags: anova, variance

I am running a one-way ANOVA and before looking at the results, the Levene test is significant. What should I do before looking/reporting at the results of my ANOVA and POST-HOC (Bonferroni).

My data looks similar to this...

```
 typeCue     cue    associate  asso.strength
    N        table    chair        0.40
    N        table    dinner       0.21
    N        table    ...          0.05
    N        home                  0.43
    N        home                  0.25
    N        home                  0.10
    A        fast                  0.30
    A        fast                  0.20
    A        fast                  0.08
    A        fun                   0.28
    A        fun                   0.19
    A        fun                   0.12
    V        run                   0.22
    V        run                   0.10
    V        run                   0.05
    V        jump                  0.19
    V        jump                  0.10
    V        jump                  0.08
```

(I left the associate column in blank because it its not important)

So, I am actually working with three associates per word (they do not sum to a 100 because originally we had 10 but for every analysis we took only the first 3.

Now my data looks like this...

```
typeCue   cue     Totalasso.strength
  N       table       0.66
  N       home        0.78
  A       fast        0.58
  A       fun         0.59
  V       run         0.37
  V       jump        0.37
```

We had a 100 participants that responded to each cue.

I am working with words and their associates. I have nouns, adjectives and verbs as cue words (cue words = words presented to the participants to which they need to produce an associate(first word that comes to mind). What I want to know is the differences between the associative strength (the probability of a the associate of being produced. This is calculated by adding the number of times an associate was produced and dividing by the total of participants). So what I want to know is the differences of the associative strength considering the three types of cues (nouns, adjectives, verbs)

So when I conduct the one-way ANOVA to see if there are differences within the cues (considering the three groups) the first problem that I encounter is that the Levene test is significant and I don't know if I just should report it like that or I should do a correction, or run another test, etc.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SPSS and this site is not about software solutions (I edited the title).  You seem to have dived straight into statistical significance testing without having a pre-specified analytical plan.   Go back to square one and develop an analytical plan, paying special attention to how the dependent variable is transformed.  Its transformation makes a world of difference in assessing equality of variances.

Comment: I am working with words and their associates. I have nouns, adjectives and verbs as cue words (cue words = words presented to the participants to which they need to produce an associate(first word that comes to mind). What I want to know is the differences between the associative strength (the probability of a the associate of being produced. This is calculated by adding the number of times an associate was produced and dividing by the total of participants). So what I want to know is the differences of the associative strength considering the three types of cues (nouns, adjectives, verbs).

Comment: So when I conduct the one-way ANOVA to see if there are differences within the cues (considering the three groups) the first problem that I encounter is that the Levene test is significant and I don't know if I just should report it like that or I should do a correction, or run another test, etc.  @FrankHarrell

Comment: So Y is a per-subject proportion?  Doesn't sound like a good case for parametric ANOVA but rather for a ordinal rank-based method (proportional odds model or one of its special nonparametric test cases).  But we need to understand your study design better.  What is the rawest form of the data?  It sounds as if that's a binary Y.

Comment: I think that I don't know how to correctly answer your question (my knowledge is very limited. I am an undergard). So, I edited my original question and added some data and information. @FrankHarrell

Comment: To answer the question in the _Title._ If you have normal data with possibly different variances within the levels of the factor of a one-way ANOVA, then you might use the procedure `oneway.test` in R. Maybe you know about 2-sample Welch t tests (which don't require equal variances) instead of pooled t tests. Similarly,`oneway.test` uses an adjustment to avoid the equal-variances assumption in a one-way ANOVA.// However, your data and goals are unclear to me, so I can't really answer your _Question._